# anticlockwise/clockwise of a parametric equation

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

I am having trouble understanding how to find the direction of motion of a parametric curve. For example, how do I find the direction of motion along the curve
$$ 
x = 3\sin t ,\quad  y=4\cos t 
$$
for $0 \leq t < 2\pi$.

Comment: Hint: Plot points.

Comment: Particle will move in the direction of $\frac{dy}{dx}$

Comment: Hint: for small values of $t$, $\sin t$ and $\cos t$ are positive.

Comment: @Julia Chahine: How is it different if it is a circle?

Answer (score 2):

The set of parametric eqns you described in the OP are anticlockwise. Hints:

1) The angle/parameter t is defined to go in a positive direction anti-clockwise. (1st quadrant in the graph is 0 to pi/2, 2nd quadrant pi/2 to pi etc).

2) Look at your eqns. When the value of t increases from 0 to 2pi, plot the points for x and y. What quadrant are they in and at what value of t?

Also: if you want to trace the ellipse in a clockwise path, how would you modify ur eqns so as to start from the 4th quadrant and go to the 1st?